# How do i return sum from a class

Tags: c#

Im writing a program where the user writes how many times he want to throw x-number dice and how many sides they going to have.

But i cant figure out how to return the sum om the number on each dice game..

this is the main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Dice> _Dice = new List<Dice>();
    int a = 0;
    int ggr = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("How many times do you want to repeat:"));
    while (a != ggr)
    {
    int xChoice = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("How many dice do you want to throw:"));
    int yChoice = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Write how many sides the dice will have:"));

    _Dice.Add(new Dice(xChoice,yChoice));
    a++;
    }
    int e = 1;
    foreach (var item in _Dice)
    {
        Interaction.MsgBox(string.Format("Result off game {0}: {1}", e++, item.ToString()));
    }

}
```

This is the Dice class:

```
    static int _xChoice, _yChoice;
    static int[,] dice = new int[_xChoice, _yChoice];
    public int Tostring()
{
    int a = 0;
    foreach (var item in dice)
    {
        a+=item;
    }
    return a;
}
    void throw()
    {
      Random r = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i <dice.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j  = 0; j < dice.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                dice[i, j] = r.Next(1, _yChoice); 
            }
        }

  }

    public Dice(int Xchoice, int Ychoice)
    {
        _xChoice = Xchoice;
        _yChoice = Ychoice;
    }
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do it like this:

```
 void throw()
    {

      Random r = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i <dice.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            int totalSum = 0;
            for (int j  = 0; j < dice.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                dice[i, j] = r.Next(1, _yChoice);
                totalSum += dice[i, j];
            }
            // Here you display totalSum for game with index i.
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, what you are asking for is the sum of items of a `2D array`:

`int total = Enumerable.Range(0, _xChoice).Sum(s => Enumerable.Range(0, _yChoice).Sum(p => dice[s, p]));`